# SQL JOIN with SQL Database + PhoneGap

Tags: mysql, sql, database, cordova

I have a table called "lists", a table "products" and a table "lists_has_products".

My Table **lists**:

> - id
> - name
> - imgsrc

My Table **products**:

> - id
> - name
> - imgsrc
> - categoryid

My Table **lists_has_products**:

> - listid
> - productid

I want to select all products where the listid is equal to ... .
How can I do this? I already tried this with no result: (I'm working with phonegap)

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS INNER JOIN LISTS_HAS_PRODUCTS ON listid = " + listid, [], onSelectSupermarketsSuccess, onTxError);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p, lists_has_products l
WHERE p.id = l.productid AND listid = "give_a_list_id_here"
```

Just putting that in the code -

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM products p, lists_has_products l WHERE p.id = l.productid AND listid = ?", [listid] , onSelectSupermarketsSuccess, onTxError);
```

Comment: @niels123 check `executeSQL` syntax.