# Web SQL join query not consistently working on Phonegap Android only

Tags: javascript, android, sql, cordova, web-sql

I'm trying to run the following Web SQL query in a Phonegap application:

```
db.transaction( function(tx) { 
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM EVENT,RESPONSE WHERE EVENT.event_id=RESPONSE.event_id AND EVENT.event_id=291 AND EVENT.persona_id=3', [], function(tx, results) { 
        console.log(results);
        window.results = results;
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }); 
});
```

In Chrome, Android Browser & iOS this works fine, but in some cases within the compiled PhoneGap Android app it doesn't, returning 0 rows.

I've done some debugging by simplifying the query and the following work:

`SELECT * FROM EVENT WHERE event_id=291 AND persona_id=3`

`SELECT * FROM RESPONSE WHERE event_id=291`

It seems to be the WHERE / JOIN parts of the query that are bugging out, but I can't seem to isolate why this would only be happening in the Android PhoneGap inline web view and nowhere else.

Is anyone aware of any differences in the web view that might be causing this, or come across something similar?

Comment: take look in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626666/sql-join-with-sql-database-phonegap

Comment: Changed the query to `SELECT * FROM EVENT e, RESPONSE r WHERE e.event_id=r.event_id AND e.event_id=291 AND e.persona_id=3`. This still returns 3 rows in Chrome but 0 in PhoneGap.

Comment: are you find any errors in LOGCAT ?

Comment: I don't have an Android dev environment setup (using Build and Xcode). I've got a Weinre instance running for debugging, and there's no error messages coming through `executeSQL`

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference, but try an ANSI standard join syntax instead: "SELECT * FROM EVENT e INNER JOIN RESPONSE r ON e.event_id=r.event_id WHERE e.event_id=291 AND e.persona_id=3"

Comment: Yeah tried with no luck :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen similar data truncation behaviour before, but not related to joins. How big is your webSQL database? Check the `size` value of your `window.openDatabase()` command, it may be too small for your database.

```
window.openDatabase(name, version, display_name, size);
```